# Why isn't a direct call to my JavaScript function being recognized?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When running this code I can't seem to figure out why I get the following error, when the function `swapImage2()` is called from within `swapImage()`:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: swapImage2 is not defined`

Here is all of my JavaScript/jQuery code of any concern to this problem (**It will most likely not be necessary to read all of this code in its entirety, but I have been warned to post my 'complete' code.**).

```
jQuery(function ($) {
//Slideshow functionality
    var paths = new Array();
    var timer = new Array();
    var pathsString = "";
    var i = 0;
    var panel = $("img#slideShowImage");
    var fTimer;
    var tTimer;
    var t2Timer;
    var fadingOut = false;
    var slideShowOn = false;
    var showTimer;
    var requestSlideShow = $.ajax({
        url: "/AJAX Pages/Compute_Slide_Show.cshtml",
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            paths = response.split("/*\\");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            paths[0] = "Okmulgee_Clock_2";
        }
    });

    if (paths.length > 0) {
        console.log("*" + paths[0] + "*");
        panel.attr("src", "/Images/SlideShowPics/" + paths[0])
        if (paths.length > 1) {
            swapImage();
        }
    }
    else {
        panel.attr("src", "/Images/City_Images/Okmulgee_Clock_2.jpg");
    }

    function runSlideShow() {  //Calls the swapImage function to begin or resume the slide show
        if (slideShowOn == false) {
            slideShowOn = true;
            if (fadingOut == false) {
                clearTimeouts();
            }
            showTimer = setTimeout("swapImage();", 1552);
        }
    };

    function stopSlideShow() {  //Pauses the slide show
        clearTimeout(showTimer);
        if (fadingOut == true) {
            fTimer = setTimeout("clearTimeouts()", 1551);
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(tTimer);
            clearTimeouts();
        }
        slideShowOn = false;
    };

    function swapImage() {  //Fades out the slideshow image
        tTimer = setTimeout("fadingOut=true", 4549);
        timer[0] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.9'", 4550);
        timer[1] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:90)'", 4550);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[2] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.8'", 4600);
        timer[3] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:80)'", 4600);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[4] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.7'", 4650);
        timer[5] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:70)'", 4650);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[6] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.6'", 4700);
        timer[7] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:60)'", 4700);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[8] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.5'", 4750);
        timer[9] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:50)'", 4750);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[10] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.4'", 4800);
        timer[11] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:40)'", 4800);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[12] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.3'", 4850);
        timer[13] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:30)'", 4850);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[14] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.2'", 4900);
        timer[15] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:20)'", 4900);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[16] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.1'", 4950);
        timer[17] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:10)'", 4950);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[18] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0'", 5000);
        timer[19] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:0)'", 5000);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[20] = setTimeout("swapImage2()", 5050);
    }

    function swapImage2() {  //Changes and fades in the slideshow image
        panel.attr("src", "/Images/SlideShowPics/" + paths[i]);
        if (i < paths.length - 1) {
            i++;
        }
        else {
            i = 0;
        }
        timer[21] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.1'", 550);
        timer[22] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:10)'", 550);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[23] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.2'", 600);
        timer[24] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:20)'", 600);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[25] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.3'", 650);
        timer[26] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:30)'", 650);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[27] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.4'", 700);
        timer[28] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:40)'", 700);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[29] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.5'", 750);
        timer[30] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:50)'", 750);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[31] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.6'", 800);
        timer[32] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:60)'", 800);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[33] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.7'", 850);
        timer[34] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:70)'", 850);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[35] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.8'", 900);
        timer[36] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:80)'", 900);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[37] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.9'", 950);
        timer[38] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:90)'", 950);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        timer[39] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='1'", 1000);
        timer[40] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:100)'", 1000);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
        t2Timer = setTimeout("fadingOut=false", 1050);
        timer[41] = setTimeout("swapImage()", 1050);
    }

    function clearTimeouts() {  //Clears all slide show timers
        for (key in timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer[key]);
        }
    }
});
```

I also get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: runSlideShow is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: stopSlideShow is not defined` when mousing over or mousing out of the image element, respectively.

Lastly, I know that this function works to perfection, as I have used it 'as is' before, except for two distinct differences. `1):` I am getting the values for the 'paths' array from an AJAX function that grabs the file name values from the server, after it uses SQL to query a database (I used to do it through JSON) *Please note, that this is not the issue, because I have tested the values of the 'paths' array after it is done communicating with the server, and the values are exactly as I expect them to be* AND `2):` I have wrapped all of the code in the standard `jQuery(function ($) {...});` jQuery wrapper *It is very likely that the problem resides as a result of this*.

This is most likely a simple answer of how I have not organized my functions correctly in a jQuery environment, or maybe not passing in the `$` as an argument, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Passing strings to `setTimeout()` is a bad, bad practice.  Pass functions!

Comment: @Pointy Why? Is that, exactly?

Comment: @VoidKing there are a few other reasons, among them performances, and the MDN explicitly tells you should pass a string (see end of my answer) but the fact that simply in your case it wouldn't work to pass a string should be a good reason, no ? ;)

Comment: @dystroy Well, I could make (at least some of it) work by placing it outside the jQuery wrapper (I'm not gonna do that, now that I'm told it is bad practice), but I ask for my education's sake. Thank you!

Comment: @VoidKing well for one thing, in my opinion it's *always* a pain to have to worry about code in a string; it's a "code smell".  Syntax errors don't get checked when you think they should, and you end up with a lot of "Don't Repeat Yourself" violations. Because functions are so easily dealt with in JavaScript, there are only very rare occasions to build code with strings.

Comment: @dystroy Well, I appreciate the info.  Until now, I just thought that setTimeout's first argument always expected a string.

Comment: @dystroy Here's another question for you that I am curious about: Why is it `slideShowImage` and not `slideShowImage()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because `swapImage2` is only defined in the scope of the callback you give to `$(document).ready`, it's not visible from the global context.

Change

```
    timer[20] = setTimeout("swapImage2()", 5050);
```

to

```
    timer[20] = setTimeout(swapImage2, 5050);
```

so that instead of asking `setTimeout` to evaluate a string in the global context, you ask it to execute the function you pass.

More generally, don't pass strings to `setTimeout` but functions. This means you should also replace

```
timer[0] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.opacity='0.9'", 4550);
timer[1] = setTimeout("document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style.filter='alpha(opacity:90)'", 4550);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
```

with

```
var style = document.getElementById('slideShowImage').style;
timer[0] = setTimeout(function(){style.opacity='0.9'}, 4550);
timer[1] = setTimeout(function(){style.filter='alpha(opacity:90)'}, 4550);  //For IE 8 & Earlier
```

---

Note [the documentation of setTimeout on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) : it is specifically written that passing code instead of a function is not recommended.

Comment: That syntax is preferred anyway

Comment: Wow, you must be right, look at all those upvotes! But, pray tell, what is the difference between "swapImage2()" and swapImage2 with respect to the problem? I mean I know one is a string, but how does this change magically put it back in scope? I am utterly confused about that part.. Oh, and thnx for the answer btw.

Comment: The string is evaluated it the global context, and swapImage2 is local .

Comment: @dystroy OH, you mean it is looking for it outside of the `jQuery(function($) {...});` wrapper?

Comment: Yes. All variables are scoped, and this scope is either the global context or the function in which they were defined.

Comment: @dystroy Also don't forget to change `tTimer=setTimeout("fadingOut=true",4549);` and `t2Timer=setTimeout("fadingOut=false",1050);` to `tTimer = setTimeout(function(){fadingOut = true}, 4549);` and `t2Timer = setTimeout(function(){fadingOut = false}, 1050);`. I had a hell of a time getting this to work correctly until I pinned that one down.

Comment: @dystroy It is also worth it to note in your answer (for sake of completion) that since I was using jQuery, it would be cleaner to condense my calls to the opacity changing into a simple jQuery `.css` function. Because jQuery handles the compatibility issues for me, I need not write every call twice (once for IE [alpha:opacity] and once for all other browsers). A simple call looks like this in my working code now: `timer[21] = setTimeout(function(){$('img#slideShowImage').css('opacity', '0.1')}, 550);`